# What to do about side window condensation

Tags: ac, window, cold-weather

I live near the ocean, so the air is very humid.  In the summertime, running the air conditioner causes condensation to form on the outside of all my windows.  This isn't a problem for the front and wear windshield, as they have built in defrosters.  However, the side windows fog up to the point I cant see out of them.  I have to lower them to see when Im turning.  Unfortunately, lowering them, then raising them doesn't clear the window of condensation.  Also, letting in a bunch of cold air isn't pleasant.

Is there anything I can do to keep the side windows from fogging up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a product like [Rain-X Anti Fog](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Rain-X-Anti-Fog-3-5oz-Bottle-AF21106DW/16889024) (no affiliation). I believe these place a superhyrdophobic film on the window. It doesn't let the water (humidity from the air) land on it, therefore no fog develops. There are probably other products out there like Rain-X ... you'll have to figure out what you can get and what might work best for you.

Comment: Not affiliated here neither...I had the same situation, I live near the coast in an island where sea breeze actually cross the whole country. I found two Rain X products here, one for outside (yellow bottle) and one for inside (black bottle, I think). Both worked for me.

Comment: Ah, Ive heard of Rain-X, but didnt realize they had Anti-Fog.